# How to get user's OU programmatically with ldap C++

Tags: mfc, ldap, visual-c++, unmanaged, native

how to get user's ou programmatically with ldap C++

Answer (score 0):

Well if you can get the users full DN, which is usually needed for the bind, then chop off the first something=something, and you have the OU.